# How best to randomly select a number of non zero elements from an array with many duplicate integers

Tags: python, numpy

I need to randomly select x non-zero integers from an unsorted 1D numpy array containing y integer elements including an unknown number of zeros as well as duplicate integers. The output should include duplicate integers if required by this random selection. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to select the non-zero elements first then use `random.choice()` (with the `replace` parameter set to either True or False) to select a given number of elements.

Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng() # doing this is recommended by numpy

n = 4 # number of non-zero samples

arr = np.array([1,2,0,0,4,2,3,0,0,4,2,1])
non_zero_arr = arr[arr!=0]

rng.choice(non_zero_arr, n, replace=True)
```

Comment: That's good but running my data set [1 2 0 0 1 2 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
selecting 6 numbers gave [1 2 1 1 1 2] but there are only 3 1's in the set. I want to pick randomly from the numbers present as if I was selecting coins from a bag. There might be 3 1p coins in which case 0, 1, 2 or 3 might be drawn but 4 couldn't.

Comment: OK I think I have it now - just a minor tweak. I think I'm right to say all I need to do is change replace=True to replace=False. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't specify that clearly. Glad you figured it out! That is precisely the purpose of the `replace` parameter.